# Trying to make a recursive program that removes a word from a list

Tags: python, recursion

```
def main():

    def remove(alist,word):
        if alist[0] == word:
            return remove(alist[1:],word)
        else:
            return [alist[0]] + remove(alist[1:],word)

    list1 = ['dog','cat','horse','dog','cat','horse']

    print(remove(list1,'dog'))

main()
```

This is my code. I'm not sure whats wrong with it. There is an error that says index out of range which I believe has to do with my third line but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: eventually alist will be empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is that you never test if alist is empty.  Since you keep removing the first element, eventually there won't be any elements left, and alist[0] will be an index out of range.  If you just add

```
if not alist:
    return []
```

to the top of remove, I bet you'll be in good shape.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks. does that basically cause it to add up all the objects that have been queued by the recursive function? Just want to make sure I'm properly understanding what that part of code does!

Comment: What you're doing is tearing the whole list apart then building it back up one element at a time as long as the element isn't what you're trying to remove.  The empty test gives you the the empty list to start adding all the other elements back into as you "unwind" the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, this line:

```
if alist[0] == word:
```

Is trying to compare the first item in `alist` with `word`, but `alist` has no items.